# Shoutcast Script Does Not Work with Names that Have an Apostrophe

Tags: php, shoutcast

Please help me I don't know what to do. Tried `urlencode` but does not work
UTF-8 does not works. I need the script can read apostrophe for display image but nothing to do I am not a programmer and now I need your help for solve this problem.

```
<?php
$cover_d = 'http://metalrockpopradio.caramania.com/blackblack.gif';  
$sc_url_ip = "69.175.13.131"; 
$sc_url_port = "8050"; 

function getNowPlaying($sc_url_ip,$sc_url_port) {

  $open = fsockopen($sc_url_ip,$sc_url_port,$errno,$errstr,'.5'); 
  if ($open) { 
    fputs($open,"GET /7.html HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent:Mozilla\n\n"); 
    stream_set_timeout($open,'1');
    $read = fread($open,200);
    $text = explode(",",$read);
    if($text[6] == '' || $text[6] == '</body></html>') { 
      $msg = ' live stream  '; 
    } else { 
      $msg = $text[6]; 
    }
    $text = $msg; 
  } else {  
    return false; 
  } 
  fclose($open);

  return $text; 
}

$current_song = getNowPlaying($sc_url_ip,$sc_url_port);
$current_song = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $current_song);
$singinfo = explode(" - ",$current_song);

$artist = urlencode($singinfo[0]);
$titel = urlencode(strip_tags($singinfo[1]));

$imgurl = @file_get_contents("http://api.depubliekeomroep.nl /anp/albumart.php?artiest=".$artist."&titel=".$titel."&size=extralarge");

if ($imgurl != "") {
  print "<img src=\"" . $imgurl . "\">";
} else { 
  print "<img src=\"" . $cover_d . "\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: `%27` i.e. urlencode. This worked fine for me. `var_dump(file_get_contents('http://api.depubliekeomroep.nl/anp/albumart.php?artiest=Tom%20Petty&titel=I%20won%27t%20back%20down&size=extralarge'));`. Side note, try and avoid `@`. Let the warning get emitted and check the return value as needed.

Comment: how i do it? do you have example?

Comment: str_replace(" ' ", '%27') ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We are talking about ASCII 39 yes? I mean this even works...

```
<?php

$artist = "Tom Petty";
$title = "I won't back down";
$uri = "http://api.depubliekeomroep.nl/anp/albumart.php?artiest={$artist}&titel={$title}&size=extralarge";

var_dump(file_get_contents($uri));
```

> 'https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/05600d9c77a9288add89fac53d3482e7.png'
>   (length=82)

Maybe provide an example of the actual string giving you trouble?

While the above works for me it might be dependent on underlying wrapper.

Best practice would be:

```
$title = urlencode("I won't back down");
```

Comment: tried urlencode : $titel = urlencode(strip_tags($singinfo[1]));

Comment: Print out the value of `$singinfo[1]`? Is it what you expect? You've never shared the actual string causing the issue. Are you getting any errors?  What does `file_get_contents` return? Don't use `@` to suppress.

Comment: Kiss+C%26apos%3BMon+And+Love+Me%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E

Comment: Kiss - C'Mon And Love Me

Comment: Great! So that url-decodes to, `Kiss C&apos;Mon And Love Me</body></html>.  `Looks like you have an HTML entity in there (and some HTML elements... Maybe that is by accident?)! Convert that HTML entity with [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) into a character. The API doesn't like `&apos;` It want's the character, (ASCII 39)